# Включение и выключение таблиц стилей

Tags: javascript, html

```
function enableSS(sheetid, enabled) { document.getElementById(sheetid).disabled = !enabled;
}


<form>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="enableSS('ss0', this.checked)">style0<br>    
<input type="checkbox" onclick="enableSS('ss1', this.checked)">style1<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="enableSS('ss2', this.checked)">style2<br>
</form>              

<link id="ss0" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style0.css">
<link id="ss1" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css">
<link id="ss2" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css">
```

Как можно сделать переключение `css` не `input`-ом, а списком `li` ну или хотябы ссылкой. Т.е на какую нажал тот файл стилей и загрузился.

Как нибудь так

```
<ul class="colors">
    <li>style0</li>                    
    <li>style1</li>
    <li>style2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `load` отслеживает когда загрузилась страничка, можно и раньше начать загружать нужный стиль, который мы возьмем из `localStorage`

```
// Сохранение темы в localStorage
const saveCssTheme = function (theme) {
    localStorage.cssTheme = theme;
}

// Получение темы из localStorage, либо дефолтной
const getCssTheme = function () {
    return localStorage.cssTheme || 'default-theme';
}

// Загрузка css файла
const loadCssTheme = function (theme) {
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = theme;
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = `/css/${theme}.css`;

    // если мы уже загрузили стили, то не нужно делать это еще раз
    if(document.getElementById(theme)) return;

    document.head.appendChild(link);
}

// Установка темы
const setCssTheme = function(theme) {
    loadCssTheme(theme);
    saveCssTheme(theme);
    document.body.setAttribute('class', theme);
}

// Использование при загрузке страницы
document.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const theme = getCssTheme();

    setCssTheme(theme);
});
```

В `css` пусть по умолчанию будет стандартная тема, остальные же будут выглядеть так

```
body.theme a {} // стиль примениться к элементу a, только если у body есть класс theme
body.theme h1 {}
```

**UPD**
Кнопки для включения

```
<ul class="colors">
    <li onclick="setCssTheme('theme0')">style0</li>                
    <li onclick="setCssTheme('theme1')">style1</li>
    <li onclick="setCssTheme('theme2')">style2</li>
</ul>
```

**UPD**
Класс для `body` необходим для того, что бы css-темы не перекрывали друг друга, если справляетесь без этого, просто удалите соответствующий код

Если не работает первоначальная загрузка тем, попробуйте так:

```
document.onload = function () {
    const theme = getCssTheme();

    setCssTheme(theme);
};
```

Либо в вопросе добавьте, то как используете мой код

Comment: мне этого мало, нужно файлы стилей и с сохранением.

Comment: @steep, что значит с сохранением?

Comment: при переходам по страницам, чтобы выбранный стиль сохранялся

Comment: Не понял на счёт этого `body.theme a{}`

Comment: И какие кнопки для включения?

Comment: Чтобы стиль сохранялся - сохраните его в `localstorage`. А потом на каждой странице `onload` присоединяйте его как стиль (<style> тег)

Comment: Не понятно. При клике на кнопку добавляется класс к `body`, зачем? И ничего не сохраняется. А так переключение работает. Как localstorage подправить.

Comment: @ThisMan Всё работает, но не сохраняет после обновления страницы. Может через cookies как попробовать, но тоже не знаю